# Angular CLI stopped giving me sensible lines (no sourcemap) in browser console, terminal however shows correct source

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I noticed a few days ago that my Angular with Angular CLI project stopped giving me a sensible error line. Instead I get lines from `main.js`, `vendor.js` and all other compiled code files. In my terminal it is giving me a 'normal' error and the correct line in the non compiled code.

Also `console.log()` in the browser console are coming from compiled code. I can't figure out what changed and if this was intentional? I have checked my environment and it runs in development mode. I have updated Angular CLI and Angular itself but to no avail.

I run this command to open a localhost:

`ng serve --open`

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fqm19",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "node deploy"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.2",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.7.0",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^6.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-adsense": "^5.4.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.55",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.9.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "ftp-deploy": "^2.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Anyone can shed a light on this change? Or did I miss something?
Oh and yes I have thrown away all my node modules and reinstalled everything. Still the same.

Angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fqm19": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/ads.txt",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fqm19:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "fqm19:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fqm19:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "fqm19-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "fqm19:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "fqm19:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "fqm19",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "css"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of `^` prefixed versions which just means "anything more than this". So possibly someone released something and you pulled in the new version and it works differently. Your package lock file should show what you've actually pulled in for these various libraries. Won't help with knowing what you *used* to be running unless you've got the package lock checked in somewhere.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Ok, will check that.I have it in my repo, but I am not sure if it changed lately.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas package lock did change indeed with the introduction of firebase and firestore. Sorry for my previous comment. Could be that they messed up something.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It was Firefox console...Chrome works.

Answer (score 2):

Check angular.json file if it contains the sourceMaps flag, and if it is set to true for development. By default, in production it is disabled (makes sense to skip debugging in production), but maybe someone updated your angular.json config without your knowledge.

Comment: I see only a flag for production config. Have tried to change that, nope. Same.

Comment: Did you tried to add a development object with sourceMaps set to true?

Comment: Also try to run ng serve --prod --source-map and see if there is any difference

Comment: Will get back to you, for good measure I always restart the server to be sure. Thnx anyway.

Comment: I have updated my question with my `angular.json` file btw. Where would I put an extra flag? I have tried in both config objects with `serve: {sourceMap:true}`. Also, it did not change anything to serve a production build with sourcemap enabled.